# breadcrumb text middle /center aline

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have been trying to aline the text in breadcrumb for about two days can't seem to get it to work.

```
.tickets_1 {
    float: left;
}
.tickets_2 {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 2px 0px;
    margin-top: 335px;
    background-color: #2E3739;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


<div class="breadcrumb">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="tickets_1">
<span> <?php echo  $sitetitle ?></span>
</div>
<div class="tickets_2">
<ul>
 <?php

                if ($thisclient && is_object($thisclient) && $thisclient->isValid()) { ?>   

                <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>account.php"><span> Hi, <?php echo Format::htmlchars($thisclient->getName());
                 ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>tickets.php">Tickets <b>(<?php echo $thisclient->getNumTickets(); ?>)</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $signout_url; ?>">Sign Out</a></li>
            <?php
            } 
            elseif($nav) {
                if ($cfg->getClientRegistrationMode() == 'public') { ?>
                    <?php

                }
                if ($cfg->getClientRegistrationMode() != 'disabled') { ?>
                   <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>account.php">register</a></li>
                   <li><a href="<?php echo $signin_url; ?>">Sign In</a></li>
<?php
                }
            } ?>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I try text-aline but didn't work any help

i have home on the left and login information on the right

thank you

Comment: I think its `text-align`. Can you post a fiddle with your code.

Comment: your `tickets_1` and `tickets_2` are floating. If you remove that and do a `text-align:center;` for breadcrumb, it works http://jsfiddle.net/Au8B9/